# MVC linq keeps returning the last row of data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm trying to get some data from 3 combined tables.

My class is `ProizvedeniProizvodiBO` which consists of three classes within it (`ProizvodBO`, `ProizvodjacBO`, `ProizvodnjaBO`). The classes all mimic the structure of tables.

Here's the code:

```
public IEnumerable<ProizvedeniProizvodiBO> NadjiProizvod(int idProizvoda)
{
            List<ProizvedeniProizvodiBO> lista = new List<ProizvedeniProizvodiBO>();
            Proizvod proizvod = azilEntities.Proizvods.FirstOrDefault(x => x.idProizvoda == idProizvoda);
            ProizvodBO trazeniProizvod = new ProizvodBO();
            ProizvodjacBO trazeniProizvodjac = new ProizvodjacBO();
            ProizvodnjaBO trazenaProizvodnja = new ProizvodnjaBO();
            ProizvedeniProizvodiBO noviProizvedeniProizvod = new ProizvedeniProizvodiBO();
            trazeniProizvod.IdProizvoda = proizvod.idProizvoda;
            trazeniProizvod.Kolicina = proizvod.kolicina;
            trazeniProizvod.NazivProizvoda = proizvod.nazivProizvoda;

            foreach (Proizvodnja proizvodnja in azilEntities.Proizvodnjas.Where(x => x.idProizvoda == idProizvoda))
            {
                trazenaProizvodnja.IdProizvoda = proizvodnja.idProizvoda;
                trazenaProizvodnja.IdProizvodjaca = proizvodnja.idProizvodjaca;
                trazenaProizvodnja.DostupneKolicine = proizvodnja.dostupneKolicine;

                Proizvodjac proizvodjac = azilEntities.Proizvodjacs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.idProizvodjaca == proizvodnja.idProizvodjaca);
                trazeniProizvodjac.IdProizvodjaca = proizvodjac.idProizvodjaca;
                trazeniProizvodjac.NazivProizvodjaca = proizvodjac.nazivProizvodjaca;
                trazeniProizvodjac.Grad = proizvodjac.grad;
                trazeniProizvodjac.Ulica = proizvodjac.ulica;
                noviProizvedeniProizvod.proizvod = trazeniProizvod;
                noviProizvedeniProizvod.proizvodjac = trazeniProizvodjac;
                noviProizvedeniProizvod.proizvodnja = trazenaProizvodnja;
                lista.Add(noviProizvedeniProizvod);
            }
            return lista;
}
```

It returns the correct amount of rows (let's say there's 3 different combinations) but every row it returns is absolutely the same, and always the last row (I manually checked).

I tried running the relevant commands in SQL and they work as they should.

I am forwarding the data to a view.

`Proizvod` would basically translate to `Product`, `Proizvodjac` to `producer` and `Proizvodnja` is the table in the middle that is connecting them. `Proizvodnja` has 2 primary keys (`idProizvoda` and `idProizvodjaca`).

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to move instantiating of your objects to your `foreach` loop, then everything works as expected, something like this:

```
foreach (Proizvodnja proizvodnja in azilEntities.Proizvodnjas.Where(x => x.idProizvoda == idProizvoda))
{
    ProizvedeniProizvodiBO noviProizvedeniProizvod = new ProizvedeniProizvodiBO();
```

The reason is `ProizvedeniProizvodiBO` is a [reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) so actually, when you are creating a new object outside of the loop and then assigning the values to the new object every time in your loop it will override the last data because it is a reference type. Therefore all of items inside your list are referring to the same object.

Comment: That is such an obvious mistake god damn. I was stumped for so long. I did not know about the fact that it's a reference type, that makes a lot more sense.

I'm practically dead tired now but I'll try it in the morning.

Comment: you nailed it bro.